# Regex to check if html tag contains string or anything?

Tags: javascript, regex

How can i check for content between any html tags?

For example this value: `<strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>`

How can i match the value between the strong tags?

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('strong')[0].innerHTML` Otherwise, [don't use regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @SvenTheSurfer i wrote the question badly, i dont like to parse html in document, im getting the <strong></strong> value in variable with knockoutJS, using tinymce editor, so i want to match the content between the tags,and all that is stored in variable...

Comment: If you're sure of the format you can use any regex like `/<strong>(.*)<\/strong>/`.